# How can I make the network manager automatically connect to a new network?

Tags: network-manager, automation

If my computer is on without an network connection(e.g. the router is rebooted, the network cable is unplugged, etc), it won't connect at all until I fix the connection then reboot the computer.  How can I make the network manager automatically connect to a new network?

**EDIT:** [Here is the log file edited to only show Network Manager.  It only show a couple hours as the file is somewhat repetitive.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/544111/)

Comment: By default, Network Manager should automatically attempt to connect when possible. If yours only works after rebooting, this sounds like a bug.

Comment: Is this the same problem you asked about in [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17270/why-wont-my-linux-computers-recognize-a-restarted-router-without-a-reboot-themse)?

Comment: @Aendruk: A bug in what?  In the comments below his answer, Stefano Palazzo Told me to ask this question.  That question asks why, this questions ask how to fix it.  Just making sure I cover all bases before assuming it's a bug.

Comment: It seems like a bug, certainly. This question is to find out how to work around it, or if it's an issue of configuration.

Comment: @John Possibly network-manager, nm-applet, or the network interface driver. In order to find out, it would help to know what items are listed in the "Wired Network" section of the menu that appears when you click the NetworkManager Applet, what driver is in use, whether [shroff's suggestion](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17270/why-wont-my-linux-computers-recognize-a-restarted-router-without-a-reboot-themse/17337#17337) works, and whether there are any error messages from `NetworkManager` in System ▸ Administration ▸ Log File Viewer ▸ daemon.log, for a start.

Comment: @aendruk: I don't know how to open Network Manager.  I can't find a menu item for it.  It always just started itself.  I know I *have* it, because it was writing to the log you mentioned.  A few warnings, but no errors that I saw.

Comment: @John right click on the network icon near the clock to get the networking information; please also add the logs to your question, you can use [paste.ubuntu.com](http://paste.ubuntu.com) for long files

Comment: @Stefano: Done.

Comment: When I reboot the router in my home network, I (always) have to restart NetworkManager/network-manager (Fedora 10 I know, I need to upgrade, Ubuntu 14.04) on all `wired` connections (wireless connections seem to resolve themselves).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can open your network manger, then open your normally chosen network connection. You then can put a click in the connect automatically, it's at the top.

Answer (score 0):

I find that simply unplugging my ethernet cable and and plugging it in again works. It has to do with the device not pick up that the cable is connected.

I also use mii-tool

```
sudo mii-tool -v  
eth1: negotiated 1000baseT-FD flow-control, link ok  
  product info: vendor 00:07:32, model 17 rev 2  
  basic mode:   autonegotiation enabled  
  basic status: autonegotiation complete, link ok  
  capabilities: 1000baseT-HD 1000baseT-FD 100baseTx-FD 100baseTx-HD 10baseT-FD 10baseT-HD  
  advertising:  1000baseT-FD 100baseTx-FD 100baseTx-HD 10baseT-FD 10baseT-HD flow-control  
  link partner: 1000baseT-HD 1000baseT-FD 100baseTx-FD 100baseTx-HD 10baseT-FD 10baseT-HD flow-control
```

then
`sudo mii-tool -R`
reset MII to poweron state 
`sudo mii-tool -r` restart autonegotiation

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth I noticed some WARN lines output in the syslog but I have exactly the same lines and do not have the same problem.

I always tell my son not to be afraid to ask stupid questions so here goes.. is the Network Applet - Edit Connections - Eth2 - Edit - "Connect Automatically" checked?

Comment: Yes it is.  Remember this is an old question.  I have not had to reboot my router since asking this so I don't know if this is still a problem.